# Hibernate/JPA Auto-Updating my entity master-detail

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jpa

I have a relationship @OneToMany with Car --> Tools. Tools are previously registered in System, after they're used in Cars. I have the following code:

```
public void addToolToCar(ActionEvent event){
 if (car == null)
 car = new Car();

 Tool tool = findToolByNumer('1234');
 tool.setSituation('PUTTED');
 car.addTool(tool);

 /*
  After adding the first Tool object to Car, everything is fine, but when i try
  to find the Tool '667', the Hibernate UPDATE in PostgreSQL the Tool '1234'. 
    The  BIG problem is that user can choose don't click in "save button" and the Car                  will not inserted (this is complete normally and often, as a CANCEL action) but the Tool
  situation was changed, this is a problem for my bussiness rule because when Tool 
   is in "PUTTED" situation, this Tool cannot be used for another Car.

  And have a wrost situation, the Tool can be removed from the Car list, like: 
  'car.removeTool('1234'), but as Tool was changed in Database i will have a serius
  problem of consistence.
 */

  tool = findToolByNumer('667');
 tool.setSituation('PUTTED');
 car.addTool(tool);
 }

 public void save(ActionEvent event){
   dao.persist(car);
 }
```

EDIT1: The addTool method in class Car is very simples, without any mistery

```
 public Car(){
   tools = new ArrayList<Tool>();
 } 

 private List<Tool> tools;
 ...
 public void addTool(Tool tool){
   tools.add(tool);
 }
```

Comment: You're defining twice the tool instance of the Tool class in your addToolToCar method. This won't even compile, please check your code.

Comment: Sorry, this is just a error of typing, but my code is correct. I already edited in post

Comment: Please show the addTool method of the car class (better if you post the whole Car class).

Comment: Are you calling addToolToCar with in a transaction ? or the addTool running in transaction scope ?

Comment: @elbuild my addTool method is very simple, i edited my post with it. Mani, my addToolToCar is not within a transaction. But when i trigger "save" method, the dao uses a transaction.

Comment: The only thing that came into my mind without seeing JPA annotations is a faulty implementations of the equals() method on the Tool class. For what concern your issues you can always rollback in case of errors even if I suspect your issues came from a erroneous ORM conf.

Comment: i have equals() and hashcode()

Comment: Do you have a reverse relationship from Tool to Car? PS: I really don't understand your problem, so please consider reformulating the question.

Comment: Well, i solved my problem with another method. I discovered that Hibernate always make flush before query (SELECT In my case), so i just change the situation of tool to before save all Car, in this way nothing will be flushed.